# What's the default port of SSHFS?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshfs, port

I tried to Google this and I found results. Either this is not very documented, either there's something I don't understand but should.

It seems like it may be port 9876 like in the documentation, and I may wrongly assume that it doesn't use the same port as regular SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSHFS uses the same port interface which is used by the SSH protocol port `22`.

Here is a snippet from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS):

```
In computing, SSHFS (SSH Filesystem) is a filesystem client to mount and interact with directories and files located on a remote server or workstation over a normal ssh connection.
```